# How to load posts in pure JS, without using AJAX jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to implement post loading on pure JS, without using Ajax jQuery. I came across an article on the Internet how to do this, but I do not understand a few points:

1. Where do I need to set the path in fetch? (in the example: fetch(`/wp-json/blog-posts/all-posts`));
2. In the get_custom_post_types_api() function, what does the path "/all-posts" mean? Where should I write it if my blog, where posts will be loaded by clicking on the button, is located at "http://site-name.net/blog/"?

// FETCH

```js
function chunkArray(array, size) {
  const chunkyArr = [];
  let index = 0;
  while (index < array.length) {
    chunkyArr.push(array.slice(index, size + index));
    index += size;
  }
  return chunkyArr;
}

function loadButton(modifier) {
  if (modifier === "hide")
    if (button) button.style.display = "none";
  if (modifier === "show")
    if (button) button.style.display = "block";
}
const itemsContainer = document.querySelector(".cb-articles-grid__items");
const postsShown = 4;
let count = 0;
const button = document.querySelector(".load-more");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch(`/wp-json/blog-posts/all-posts`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      data.splice(0, postsShown);
      const newData = Util.chunkArray(data, postsShown);
      const currentChunk = newData[count];

      if (count <= newData.length) {
        const items = [];
        currentChunk.forEach((key, index) => {
          const postUrl = currentChunk[index].url;
          const postTitle = currentChunk[index].title;
          const postExcerpt = currentChunk[index].excerpt;
          const postImg = currentChunk[index].featured_img_src;
          const postDate = currentChunk[index].date;
          const article = `<article class="c-article-item fadeIn">
      <a class="c-article-item__link" href="${postUrl}">
        <div class="c-article-item__image">
          <img src="${postImg}" alt="${postTitle}">
        </div>
        <p class="c-article-item__date">${postDate}</p>
        <div class="c-article-item__text">
          <h3 class="c-article-item__title">${postTitle}</h3>
          <p class="c-article-item__excerpt">${postExcerpt}</p>
        </div>
      </a></article>`;
          items.push(article);
        });

        itemsContainer.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", items.join(""));
        count++;
        if (count === newData.length) loadButton("hide");
      } else {
        loadButton("hide");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Something went wrong!", err);
    });
});
```

// FUNCTION.PHP

```php
function get_blog_post_type($request) {
  $posts_data = array();
  $paged = $request->get_param('page');
  $paged = (isset($paged) || !(empty($paged))) ? $paged : 1;
  $blogPosts = get_posts(
    array(
      'post_type'       => 'post',
      'status'          => 'published',
      'posts_per_page'  => -1,
      'orderby'         => 'post_date',
      'order'           => 'DESC',
      'paged'           => $paged
    )
  );
  foreach ($blogPosts as $post) {
    $id = $post->ID;
    $post_thumbnail = (has_post_thumbnail($id)) ? get_the_post_thumbnail_url($id) : null;
    $posts_data[] = (object)array(
      'id' => $id,
      'slug' => $post->post_name,
      'type' => $post->post_type,
      'title' => $post->post_title,
      'featured_img_src' => $post_thumbnail,
      'url' => get_permalink($id),
      'excerpt' => mb_strimwidth(get_the_excerpt($id), 0, 180, '...'),
    );
  }
  return $posts_data;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'get_custom_post_types_api');
function get_custom_post_types_api() {
  register_rest_route(post', '/all-posts', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'get_blog_post_type'
  ));
}
```

// LOAD BUTTON

```
<button class="load-more"> Load more blog posts </button>
```

Comment: _Side note:_`(isset($paged) || !(empty($paged))) ? $paged : 1` can be rewritten to `!empty($paged) ? $paged : 1`. There's no reason to check both `isset()` and `!empty()` since `empty()` also checks if the variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure JS [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) where url is first parameter.

```
fetch(url, ?objectWithOtherParams).then(()=>{})
```

*/all-posts* is path for API, it is endpoint specific (wordpress in this case)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do not understand what path I should register in fetch. Path to my Blog page?

Comment: You register the route yourself in your functions.php... (where you have syntax errors by the way)